# Unitary representation with non-closed invariant subspace

Tags: representation-theory

What would be an easy example of a unitary representation of a group on a Hilbert space that is topologically irreducible(has no closed invariant subspaces)) but not algebraically irreducible (has no invariant subspaces)?
Or that has an invariant subspace that is not topologically closed?

Edit: I guess an example would be: take $V = l^2(\mathbb Z)$ and let $\mathbb Z$ act on $V$ by shift operators $T^n$. This is an unitary representation and the space of all sequences who only have finitely many entries non-zero is invariant but is not closed.

If this is ok, my next question would be if there is an anolog of this for the translation action of $\mathbb R$ on $L^2(\mathbb R)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The analogue for the translation action of $\mathbb{R}^2$ on $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ is the subspace of compactly supported functions. More generally you can pick just about any function and consider the subspace spanned by its translates.

Comment: The moment i wrote the question, i thought about the space generated by any function. Ah and I see now, any invariant dense subspace gives of course an example which leads me to the question how the closure behaves with regard to the property of being invariant: is the closure of an invariant subspace again invariant?

Comment: @Mekanik: yes. This isn't hard to see.

Comment: ok, I will take a look. Thx